# Where does Stack Overflow get the list of Recommended Readings on our Developer Stories?

Tags: discussion, questions, developer-story, personal-data

On my developer story are a list of recommended readings.

**Where does Stack Overflow get these recommendations?**

I ask because the readings recommended (two of which have nothing to with any topic on Stack Overflow) show clear evidence that additional information from my **Facebook** was used to make these recommendations. I have not searched for or mentioned these books anywhere on any Stack Exchange site.

### EDIT: False alarm. Turns out they were migrated over from another part of Stack Overflow that I had forgotten about.

[image: Recommended readings]

Comment: That's a field you can edit. At one point you put that information in.

Comment: Another Cambridge Analytica Scandal.

Comment: As far as I remember, I added my own books/recommendations there.

Comment: As a data point, I note that my own "Recommended Reading" section is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have forgotten that you have added them a long time ago, even before the Developer Story feature was released.

You can edit them in [your Developer Story tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current?view=Timeline). Just hover over the Recommended Reading section and there's an Edit button you can click on.

[image]

Comment: Good point, I forgotten that those could have even be added by OP to the CV, before Developer Story feature was released, and was migrated over.

Comment: Thank you. I must have added these myself a long time before and they were migrated over.